# Unable to launch the web application (asp.net app) in the Azure Kubernetes service (AKS). Getting site is not reachable error

Tags: azure, docker, kubernetes, azure-aks, windows-container

I have tried to host the web application to the AKS (Azure Kubernetes Service).

1. Create a sample application with docker support(windows container).

   docker file

   FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/aspnet:4.8-windowsservercore-ltsc2019
   ARG source
   WORKDIR /inetpub/wwwroot
   COPY ${source:-obj/Docker/publish}

docker-compose details as follow:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  akstestapp:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}akstestapp
    build:
      context: .\AKSTestApp
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
```

2. I have deployed the application to the Desktop docker container. I could able to deploy and launch the application.

[image]

3. Pushed the image to the Azure content Registry.

[image]

4. Tried to deploy the application to Kubernetes.

   virtualservice.networking.istio.io/aks-test-web-app created
   deployment.apps/aks-test-web-app created
   service/aks-test-web-app created

   c:/AKSConfigs>kubectl.exe get service/aks-test-web-app -w

   NAME               TYPE           CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP     PORT(S)        AGE
   aks-test-web-app   LoadBalancer   10.206.4.251   20.253.252.26   80:30614/TCP   4m14s

.
5. when I hit to the launch the application (external IP).  I am getting site not reachable error.

6. deployment yaml file as below.

   ```
     apiVersion: apps/v1
        kind: Deployment  
        metadata:  
          name: aks-test-web-app  
          labels:
            app: aks-test-web-app 
        spec:  
          replicas: 1  
          template:  
            metadata:  
              labels:  
                app: aks-test-web-app   
            spec:  
              nodeSelector:
                "beta.kubernetes.io/os": windows
              containers:
              - name: aks-test-web-app
                image: sample.azurecr.io/akstestwebapp:1
                ports:
                  - containerPort: 80
          selector:
            matchLabels:
              app: aks-test-web-app
        ---  
        apiVersion: v1  
        kind: Service  
        metadata:  
          name: aks-test-web-app   
        spec:  
          type: LoadBalancer  
          ports:  
          - port: 80  
          selector:  
            app: aks-test-web-app
   ```

and I searched in google and added routing config too.

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: aks-test-web-app
spec:
  hosts:
  - "sample.com"
  - "sample.internal"
  gateways:
  - sample
  http:
    - match:
      - uri:
          prefix: /aks-test-webapp
      route:
      - destination:
          host: aks-test-web-app.sample.svc.cluster.local
          port:
            number: 8080
```

Still, I am facing the site not reachable error. Could you please help me to figure out my mistake?

POD is running

[image]

```
 C:\Users\munirajn> kubectl.exe describe pod aks-test-web-app-84647d8585-ht9wv
Name:             aks-test-web-app-84647d8585-ht9wv
Namespace:        agys-pay
Priority:         0
Service Account:  default
Node:             akspaypgw000000/10.240.132.62
Start Time:       Thu, 15 Dec 2022 15:38:52 +0530
Labels:           app=aks-test-web-app
                  pod-template-hash=84647d8585
Annotations:      <none>
Status:           Running
IP:               10.240.132.63
IPs:
  IP:           10.240.132.63
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/aks-test-web-app-84647d8585
Containers:
  aks-test-web-app:
    Container ID:   containerd://7cf9d9221ffc011860fde2bbe5f9e226b862a6fc432912c00f475d71d24f29d3
    Image:          sample.azurecr.io/akstestwebapp:1
    Image ID:       sample.azurecr.io/akstestwebapp@sha256:aa70ce0eb14095c198472db68dfd6372f7f6905a593c508da40fdf30b055f899
    Port:           80/TCP
    Host Port:      0/TCP
    State:          Running
      Started:      Thu, 15 Dec 2022 15:39:00 +0530
    Ready:          True
    Restart Count:  0
    Environment:    <none>
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from kube-api-access-6bl9z (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True
  Ready             True
  ContainersReady   True
  PodScheduled      True
Volumes:
  kube-api-access-6bl9z:
    Type:                    Projected (a volume that contains injected data from multiple sources)
    TokenExpirationSeconds:  3607
    ConfigMapName:           kube-root-ca.crt
    ConfigMapOptional:       <nil>
    DownwardAPI:             true
QoS Class:                   BestEffort
Node-Selectors:              beta.kubernetes.io/os=windows
Tolerations:                 node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
                             node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
Events:                      <none>
```

Comment: Is your pod actually running? Have you checked it with `kubectl get pod -n mynamespace`

Comment: @silent, yes its working

Comment: @Kalai Selvi, Is issue was resolved, if not could you please provide the ingress.yaml and error description in detailed.

Comment: Where could I get the ingress.yaml , sorry I am new to azure Kubernetes. I am manually deploying to Kubernetes. I did not have ingress.yaml

Comment: could you please provide the any error screenshots / pod screenshot by running this command kubectl get pods  / kubectl describe ingress by connecting aks cluster. ?

Comment: By hitting (kubectl get pod -n mynamespace), I could see my POD is running. I attached a screenshot to my description.

Comment: In my view issue may cause because of NSG rules / load balancer, allow 80 port with load balancer IP, you can know by using this command kubectl get service "External IP indicates Load Balancer IP"  refer this tutorial for more information https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/tutorial-kubernetes-deploy-application?tabs=azure-cli

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250469/discussion-between-kalai-selvi-and-swarna-anipindi).

Answer (score 0):

Replicated the scenario using below process

**Step1:**
Created a cluster using below code

```
az aks create --resource-group v-swarna-*****--name democluster --node-count 1 --enable-addons monitoring --generate-ssh-keys
```

OutPut:
[image]

[image]

**Step2:**
Connect to cluster upon creation by using this command

```
az aks get-credentials --resource-group v-swarna-*****--name demoCluster
```

[image]

Did slight modifications on deployment yaml file

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
     kind: Deployment  
     metadata:  
       name: aks-test-web-app  
       labels:
         app: aks-test-web-app 
     spec:  
       replicas: 1  
       selector:
         matchLabels:
           app: aks-test-web-app
       template:  
         metadata:  
           labels:  
             app: aks-test-web-app   
         spec:  
           containers:
           - name: aks-test-web-app
             image: *****.azurecr.io/akstestwebapp:1
             ports:
               - containerPort: 80
     ---  
     apiVersion: v1  
     kind: Service  
     metadata:  
       name: aks-test-web-app   
     spec:  
       type: LoadBalancer  
       ports:  
       - port: 80  
       selector:  
         app: aks-test-web-app
```

Apply the change on cluster

```
kubecetl apply -f deployment.yaml
```

verify the pods or up and running by using below command

```
kubectl get pods
kubectl get service
```

verification:

run below command:

```
kubectl get service
```

NOTE: Take the public IP [External IP] from the above output Site will be accessible via public ip.